# Apache Spark: Update global variables in workers

Tags: java, hadoop, mapreduce, apache-spark

I am curious if the following simple code will work in distributed environment (it does work properly in standalone)?

```
public class TestClass {
    private static double[][] testArray = new double[4][];
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        for(int i = 0; i<4; i++)
        {
            testArray[i] = new double[10];
        }
        ...
        JavaRDD<String> testRDD = sc.textFile("testfile", 4).mapPartitionsWithIndex(
            new Function2<Integer, Iterator<String>, Iterator<String> >() {
                @Override
                public Iterator<String> call(Integer ind, Iterator<String> s) {
                    /*Update testArray[ind]*/
                }
            }, true
        );
    ...
```

If it is supposed to work, I wonder how Spark sends the portion of testArray from worker to master node?

Comment: to the vote close: this is a perfectly valid question and valuable for others as well. Don't see the reason for a close. Please leave a comment with your improvement suggestions.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**No.** It's not supposed to work in a distributed environment.

Variables captured in a closure will be serialized and sent to the workers. The data initially set at the driver will be available to the workers, but any updates at the worker level will be only accessible in the local scope.

On local, the variable is in the same memory space and therefore you see the updates, but that will not scale to a cluster.

You need to convert the computation in terms of RDD operations in order to collect the results.

Comment: Thank you! Could you please shed more light on the following statement taking into account this simple example?
>> You need to convert the computation in terms of RDD operations in order to collect the results.

Comment: There are few options. What is the `/*update testArray */` step supposed to do?